# Summing group totals = 1?

Tags: mysql, sql, reporting-services

Please help, any advice greatly appreciated. I need to produce a report which returns a total if two specific values are displayed/listed.

I have numerous individuals displaying in a report and numerous rows per individual. These rows are grouped by individual. At the end of the report, I would like a total for how many individuals have rows containing two different but specific values.

For example, I have a calculated field which returns a 1 if an adjacent cell displays "traded":

```
=IIf(Fields!Funding_Description.Value = "Traded", 1, 0)`
```

Similarly, I have a second calculated field which returns a 1 if that same cell displays "non-traded":

```
=IIf(Fields!Funding_Description.Value = "Non-traded", 1, 0)
```

As these rows of data are grouped, at the bottom of each individual I get a total for how many data rows contain "traded" and a total for how many return "non-traded" (this all works fine).

I also have a third column containing an expression (not calculated field as calculated fields cannot contain aggregates) which says:

```
=IIf(Sum(Fields!EP_Traded_Score.Value) > 0 And Sum(Fields!EP_Sutton_Score.Value) > 0, 1, 0)
```

This also works fine and a 1 is returned in the final column if the sum of each calculated field is >0, effectively showing that an individual has "traded" and "non-traded" categories associated with them.

However, what I now need is a total of the 1s in this final column. I have tried various approaches, such as putting `=Sum()` around the above expression, but every score that is returned at the bottom of the report is a 1. This is made more complicated by the fact that the third column/cell contains an expression and not a calculated field. Is there a way to perhaps 'count' the number of times a certain word appears in a whole report, and I can change the 1s to unique words/text strings?

Thanks in advance

EDIT

Many thanks for feedback. Sample image from report here as requested (showing only one individual/record):

[Report extract](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y3Y3C.png)

Comment: Maybe go back to the SQL and wrap your current query in an outer query that you can filter based on your needs?  

What version of MySQL?

Comment: MySQL doesn't support `IIF()`.  I also find the question really hard to follow without sample data and desired results *in a tabular format*.

Comment: The provided code expressions looks like MS Access expressions. Not MySQL.

Comment: As Gordon suggested, please supply a small sample of data and the expected output, it will be much easier to visualise the problem.

@Akina, the expressions are SSRS expressions in the OPs report

Comment: Many thanks for this. Yes the expressions are SSRS using Microsoft Report Builder. The image highlights a cell containing a 1 because the sums of the previous two columns are >0. I need to total the final column

Comment: `IIF` is supported in SQL Server or MSSQL. Please edit tags to your actual DBMS accordingly.

Comment: And why not add the expressions: `= IIf(Fields!Funding_Description.Value = "Traded", 1, 0) + IIf(Fields!Funding_Description.Value = "Non-traded", 1, 0)`?